# VS2012 Could not copy the file *****.exe because it does not exist

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, build

I have a fairly simple one solution project in VS2012. Standard windows forms, no special DLLs.

I get to a point were if I add more code to any form, or add a new control, the build fails in DEBUG mode. If I remove the line or the control, it works.

If I switch to RELEASE, the build succeeds.

If I create a new configuration and copy RELEASE, then that too fails.

If I revert to VS2008, all is fine. If I then re-convert the solution, it will be fine for a while.

Anybody else see that? I have researched the cases about missing DLLs and locked files, but that doesn't seem to apply. Neither does renaming the assembly work.

Comment: Do you have all exceptions checked ? Do you have any post build event ? Did you check the warnings / errors ?

Comment: If compiling the project succeeds but only copying the EXE fails then you have a problem with your virus scanner.  Disable it or make an exclusion.

Comment: Hi there Fransu and thanks for the pointers. Yes, I have all exceptions checked and verbose comments. There are none. I have no post build events.

Comment: Hi there Hans. That's not the issue because the file does not exist to be copied. I can predictable make it fail by adding a new control or just one line of code. And in "release" the files is copied.

Answer (score 1):

After many hours of looking at the options, a workaround is to turn on optimisations in "Advanced Compile Options".

I do not know what optimisations actually optimise, but they are turned off in debug by default because the debugger doesn't like them. Apparently, they will move code around.

This is obviously only a workaround and not the cause, so any other suggestions are welcome!